# Error when loading date/time via xml SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

SQL Server 2016

I am loding bulk records via xml. I have the following query:

```
  DECLARE @xmlString VARCHAR(4000);
    SET @xmlString = N'
    <Customers>
    <OrderID>10248</OrderID>
    <CustomerID>VINET</CustomerID>
    <CreateDate>10/7/2016 7:31:06 AM</CreateDate>
     </Customers>
   ';

   DECLARE @xml XML;
   SET @xml = CONVERT(XML, @xmlString);

   INSERT  INTO [test].dbo.[customers]
    ( [OrderID] ,
      [CustomerID] ,
      [CreateDate]

    )
    SELECT  T.Customer.value('(OrderID)[1]', 'INT') AS OrderID ,
            T.Customer.value('(CustomerID)[1]', 'nvarchar(20)') AS  CustomerID ,
            T.Customer.value('(CreateDate)[1]', 'DATETIME') AS CreateDate
    FROM    @xml.nodes('Customers') AS T ( Customer );
```

If I remove the CreateDate field, this will load just fine. However, if i leave the CreateDate field in, i receive this error:

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 35
>         Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

CreateDate is a DATETIME field.

Here is the table:

```
  CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Customers](
[OrderID] [INT] NULL,
[CreateDate] [DATETIME] NOT NULL,
[CustomerID] [NVARCHAR](10) NULL
   ) ON [PRIMARY]
```

What conversion am I missing to load date/time into my table via xml? Thanks

Comment: If possible, go back to whoever created this XML for you and tell them to use ISO 8601 as the date/time format for exporting. `2016-10-07 07:31:06` has far less trouble converting. That's assuming 10/7 is MM/DD, as the "AM" seems to hint... you can never be sure with local formats.

Comment: @jeroen - I am creating the xml. I tried ISO 8601 (i.e 2006-04-18T09:58:04.570) and it still failed

Comment: I have run this code on my machine (without insert) it shows me correct datetime from XML. Maybe something with destination table? Can you show its create script?

Comment: What is second column alias in SELECT clause? typo?

Comment: CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Customers](
 [OrderID] [INT] NULL,
 [CreateDate] [DATETIME] NOT NULL,
 [CustomerID] [NCHAR](10) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

Comment: I created table and all your script ran without errors... weird

Comment: @gofr1, probably not weird at all. Just change the date to '<CreateDate>13/7/2016 7:31:06 AM</CreateDate>' and you will get this error. OP just picked - by chance - an example where month **and** day are below 12...

Comment: @Shnugo Thanks, after your comment I recognize that the date from query output is `2016-10-07 07:31:06.000` and I thought *I see* `2016-07-10 07:31:06.000`. No more questions I guess:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Use following if the XML date is in **mm/dd/yyyy** format

`CONVERT(datetime, T.Customer.value('(CreateDate)[1]', 'nvarchar(50)'), 101) AS CreateDate`

If the Date in XML is in some other format like dd/mm/yyyy - please visit below link to find out what should be placed instead of `101`

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo 'nvarchar(50)' should be there in `T.Customer.value('(CreateDate)[1]', 'nvarchar(50)')`

Comment: Perfect!...Thank you so much

Comment: Sorry for this, but this answer is far away from *Perfect*. This might work, but is absolutely the wrong advise with datetime values *within* XML. down vote from my side...

Comment: @Shnugo: You can down-vote, as many times as you like, but I only answered for specific requirement in case if OP knows the Date Time Culture format which is coming in XML, it will work without depending on SQL Server System's Date Time.

Valid Input XML is entry point, all answer will fail if instead of date, it will contain junk or null value. Hope you got the point.  . -- Nothing is perfect.

Comment: @GauravKP - I agree. I explained to Shnugo i posted a sample of my code. And nobody wants best practices more than me. But, to downvote and answer is petty. Your solution did exactly what i wanted.

Answer (score 2):

In your comment you say *I am creating the xml*. How are you doing this?

In properly created XML date/time value ought to be ISO8601.

Your few lines of code show, that you do not **think in XML**. XML is not simple text with some extra characters...

Nevertheless your format is convertable with code 131 for `dd/mm/yyyy` or 101 for `mm/dd/yyyy`, **but you should not do this!**

```
DECLARE @xml XML=
N'
    <Customers>
    <OrderID>10248</OrderID>
    <CustomerID>VINET</CustomerID>
    <CreateDate>10/7/2016 7:31:06 AM</CreateDate>
     </Customers>
  ';
SELECT c.value('OrderID[1]','int') AS OrderID
      ,c.value('CustomerID[1]','nvarchar(100)') AS CustomerID
      ,CONVERT(DATETIME,c.value('CreateDate[1]','nvarchar(100)'),101) AS CreateDate
FROM @xml.nodes('Customers') AS A(c)
```

Better try it like this

```
DECLARE @xml2 XML=
N'
    <Customers>
    <OrderID>10248</OrderID>
    <CustomerID>VINET</CustomerID>
    <CreateDate>2016-10-07T07:31:06</CreateDate>
     </Customers>
  ';
SELECT c.value('OrderID[1]','int') AS OrderID
      ,c.value('CustomerID[1]','nvarchar(100)') AS CustomerID
      ,c.value('CreateDate[1]','datetime') AS CreateDate
FROM @xml2.nodes('Customers') AS A(c)
```

Comment: This article says the same thing http://p2p.wrox.com/book-professional-sql-server-2005-xml-isbn-0-7645-9792-2/74823-problem-loading-datetime-values-xml.html. I formatted the date like above and it worked. But I'm going with @GauravKP answer. I can leave my date in the exact format as in my question and it works. Thanks, i'll up vote this.

Comment: @BoundForGlory, You can do what you want, but you should turn your nick to *BoundToTroubles* :-)

Comment: @BoundForGlory, You should re-check your output with a day over 12. The given format might look correct but could mistake month as days. It is **a really bad habit to rely on culture specific datetime formats!**

Comment: I understand what your saying and I appreciate your concern. What I'm showing is just a sample of my application. This is NOT production level code. I just wanted to convert a date/time. Thanks.